Why are datetime sliced so differently than integers in Power BI
I am trying to understand how datetime works in Power BI, and I have a date table that I am using for slicing values. It has a relationship with "Table_A" on a column called Month. Table A has an additional column made with the following DAX formula:
Month_datetime = 
VAR per2= SELECTEDVALUE(Table_A[Month])
Return per2

If I use the date table with a slicer I get the following:

However, once I change the DAX to this:
Month_datetime = 
VAR per2= SELECTEDVALUE(Table_A[Month])
VAR startdate = DATE(LEFT(per2,4),RIGHT(per2,2),"01")
Return startdate

It returns this instead:

That is, with datetime, it returns a row for each month in table A.
The way I see it, I only changed the datatype of the Month_datetime column. The slicer does not even use this column, so why is there so much difference here?
To further clarify; The Month column in Table A is an integer column. The Month column in the date table is a formatted datetime column created with the following line:
"Month", FORMAT(DATE(YEAR([Date]),MONTH([Date]),1),"YYYYMM")

However, these two columns are not changed at all; The only difference between the two images above is the DAX used to create Month_datetime.
